# Validate an ajax response against the request

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, response, validation

Is there some means in ajax and/ or jquery by which I can validate if the response I have received is for the specific request that I sent?

To make it more clear. I have a search page thts divided into two parts, the top part is the search criteria section and the second part is the matched results. By default the 1st 20 records are fetched. The results section is periodically updated via an ajax request. The user can choose to filter the provided results. This too happens via ajax.

The URL for both the requests is the same. The only difference being the filter criteria appended to the URL when the user chooses to filter the results.

Since the users filter has higher precedence than the back ground refresh I need to abort a background refresh when its detected that the user has requested a specific filer. Is there some means of checking the ajax response and validating that this response corresponds to the back ground request or user specific request?

I have tried my best to explain the query but do let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you're going for.  My understanding is that a part of your page auto-refreshes periodically, but if the user has explictly indicated a filter you want these refreshes to stop.  correct?

I don't know what your ajax responses are like, so this will have to be kind of abstract, but
I presume your ajax response is either HTML or JSON.

When you make the response for user-specified-filter requests, just add some kind of flag to indicate that this has happened.

HTML: add this to the code that is probably added to your page somewhere w/ `innerhtml`

```
<input type="hidden" id="user-defined-filter" value=1 />
```

JSON: add this to response JSON object.  I'll call it `ajaxResponse1`

```
{user-defined-filter: 1}
```

And then put a conditional before your auto-refresh such as

```
if (!$("user-defined-filter").val()) {//auto-refresh stuff
```

OR

```
if (!ajaxResponse1.user-defined-filter) {//auto-refresh stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save $.ajax() return object of the background request, and abort it on user request:

```
// global
var bgAjax;

// In you treatment og background
bgAjax = $.ajax(...);

// Abort
bgAjax.abort();
```